# Rails undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to create a select field for a form that selects based on records selected for a model (called "Cancellation_Reasons").

In my model called Cancellation:

```
<%= form_for(@cancellation do |f| %>
    <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@cancellation_reasons, :id, :name) %>
<% end %>
```

In the Cancellation_Controller:

```
def new
  @cancellation = Cancellation.new
  @cancellation_reasons = CancellationReason.find(1)    

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @trade }
  end
end
```

When I run `CancellationReason.find(1)` in the the Rails Console it finds the record, so @cancellation_reasons isn't nil.  I think that it's probably in how I'm using the select helpers (I've tried experimenting with them, but I'm not quite sure which one to use even after reading the Rails Guide and [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)).

Comment: Judging by your variable names, I expect you want multiple cancellation reasons (an array).  If that's the case, shouldn't you use `all` instead of `find`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

options_from_collection_for_select expect a collection (even it it is a collection of 1).
So change the code to be:

```
def new
  @cancellation = Cancellation.new
  @cancellation_reasons = CancellationReason.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @trade }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  How do I adjust this if I only want to pull the cancellation reasons  for when user_id = nil or current user_id.  What I'm trying to do is allow the user to select some reasons relevant for only them as well as some default ones (ie user_id = nil).  Thank you.